# A question on showing a space is not regular

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \{(x,\alpha):x \in A_\alpha, \alpha \in \omega_1\}$, in which $\{A_\alpha: \alpha \in \omega_1\}$ are pairwise disjoint, countable dense subsets
of the (open) unit interval $(0,1)$. The topology of the space $X$ is generated by the sets 
$$O(a,b,\alpha)=\{(x,\beta) \in X: a < x < b, \alpha \le \beta < \omega_1\}, 0 \le a < b \le 1, \alpha \in \omega_1\;.$$

> How to show that $X$ is not regular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$For each basic open set $O(a,b,\alpha)$ we have $\cl O(a,b,\alpha)=X\cap\big([a,b]\times\omega_1\big)$; in particular, this means that $\cl (a,b,\alpha)\supseteq\big([a,b]\cap A_0\big)\times\{0\}$. Fix $\langle x,1\rangle\in X$, and let $F=A_0\times\{0\}$; $F$ is closed in $X$, and $\langle x,1\rangle\notin F$, but for any basic open nbhd $O(a,b,1)$ of $\langle x,1\rangle$ we have

$$\cl(a,b,1)\cap F=\big([a,b]\cap A_0\big)\times\{0\}\ne\varnothing\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I show that $F$ is closed in $X$? For any $\langle x,0 \rangle \in X$, it seems that any its nbhd will intersect with $F$, because $A_0$ is dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Paul: Every $\langle x,0\rangle\in X$ is in $F$ by definition! $F$ is the complement of the open set $\{\langle x,\alpha\rangle\in X:\alpha\ge 1\}$.

Comment: For $A_0$ is just the countable dense set in $(0,1)$, why every $\langle x,0\rangle \in F$?

Comment: @Paul: Every $\langle x,0\rangle\in X$ is in $F$ by definition: $F=A_0\times\{0\}$. Remember, $\langle x,0\rangle\in X$ iff $x\in A_0$. $F$ is the bottom ‘level’ of $X$.

Comment: Yes. I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!